# Is it possible to do a FadeTransition to sides?

Tags: animation, javafx, java-2d

I would like to know if there is a way to do a FadeTransition from the right or left or even top of bottom kind of like the example here:

[image]

Comment: Yes. Try combining the example in the [`Transition` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/animation/Transition.html) for building the text with another animation (another `Transition` or a `Timeline`) that adjusts the text fill using a linear gradient. You can combine them into a single animation, or place both in a `ParallelTransition`. Post a *specific* question if you run into trouble implementing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot will try that !

Comment: You may not even need to animate the text content itself; just the gradient might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style the label with a text fill set to a linear gradient, and change the stops of the linear gradient in a timeline.

Here's a basic example (click on "Fading Label" to see the animation). A similar approach should work for fading out.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TextFade extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Label label = new Label("Fading label:");
        Label fadingLabel = new Label("text fades in and out");

        DoubleProperty startFade = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
        DoubleProperty endFade = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
        fadingLabel.styleProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> String.format(
                "-fx-text-fill: linear-gradient(to right, -fx-text-background-color 0%%, -fx-text-background-color %f%%, transparent %f%%, transparent 100%%);",
                startFade.get()*100, endFade.get()*100
        ), startFade, endFade));


        HBox root = new HBox(2, label, fadingLabel);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(startFade, 0), new KeyValue(endFade, 0)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1.0/3.0), new KeyValue(startFade, 0)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(2.0/3.0), new KeyValue(endFade, 1)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1), new KeyValue(startFade, 1)));

        label.setOnMouseClicked(e -> timeline.play());

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just got this error WARNING: CSS Error parsing '*{-fx-text-fill: linear-gradient(to right, -fx-text-background-color 0%, -fx-text-background-color 0,000000%, transparent 0,000000%, transparent 100%);}: Expected '<color>' while parsing '-fx-text-fill' at [1,101]

while copying it into eclipse oxygen

Comment: @Roku Best guess is that the number format is using your locale (so, for example, the decimal separator is a `,`), but the CSS parser is expecting numbers formatted in en-us locale. Try concatenating strings (which I admit is a bit ugly) instead of using `String.format()` to see if it fixes it.

Comment: Very sorry, had some personal issues but seems like putting in the String.format() Locale.US, fixed the css issue and works perfectly !